# PhoneGap App Rejected from Apple: Data Collection and Storage

Tags: ios, geolocation, gps, phonegap

My PhoneGap app got rejected  from Apple with the following message:

> We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access the
>   location but does not clarify the use of this feature in the
>   permission modal alert. To resolve this issue, please revise the
>   permission modal alert to specify why the app is requesting access to
>   the location.

How can I fix that?

Thank you all!

Comment: It's actually very self explanatory. You are requesting the user's location without thoroughly or clearly explaining why you are requesting it on the modal alert.

Comment: Thank you Nick, I know what I have to do but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

This needs be updated in Application's Info.plist file with the key: NSLocationUsageDescription

Provide the detailed description about why your app is using the location usage. Same text will be displayed to the user while asking the User permission in the app.

Hope it solves the issue.